# PayPal IPN in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

I am just wondering which table stored the PayPal IPN in WooCommerce. The dashboard in wordpress(woocommerce) can not see so much information in the PayPal IPN, only few of them like Payer first name,Payer last name,Payer PayPal address,Payment type,PayPal Transaction Fee. I want to see more about the IPN data such as if the paypal is verified, phone number, registered country, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your dashboard You will see:

```
Order #ORDER_NUMBER details
Payment via PayPal (`PayPal Transaction ID`).
```

In your PayPal account access `Instant Payment Notification (IPN) details` page. `profile -> selling preferences -> Instant Payment Notification Preferences`. Click  `IPN History` page and search the transaction id that you see in WooCommerce. You will see all the information about this IPN. HTTP response code, Delivery status, the actual message sent by PayPal.

You can also access the `transaction id`  from WooCommerce table.

```
select meta_value
from wp_postmeta
where post_id=ORDER_NUMBER and meta_key='_transaction_id'
```

replace `ORDER_NUMBER` with your WooCommerce  order number.

Comment: Thank you, is there any method that I can see all the information about this IPN on woocommerce order detail page? I don't want to see the transaction id only on the order detail page.

Comment: @PaulYih Not that I'm aware of. What would be the point in that? If the IPN was successful then the order status was changed to Processing. Near the date column you can see the order notes. if you pass over with the mouse on the icon you will see a message "IPN Payment Complete", if there was an error it will show you error message. What else do you require?

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the IPN message isn't stored by default, but you can set the PayPal gateway option to "debug" and you might get some more information out of that.... though obviously meant for debugging purposes and not live use.

Comment: I want to see if the seller protection [eligible/ineligible], if the paypal is verified[verified,unverified,unregisterd], buyers's phone, buyer's country... I want to see these on the order detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Some might need the IPN data from PayPal to feed into other in-house operational processes, like shop floor order processing, etc., rather than having woocommerce consume all the IPN data and only 'keep' part of it for display. Better to either save it all, or offer a configuration option to specify a 2nd IPN listener the data could be piped to, in order to facilitate automation of other order processing systems.

Comment: This appears to be a comment criticizing WooCommerce's design, rather than an answer to the question as such. Can you [edit] to clarify or correct this?